# Creating an animation scrubber in unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a scrubber for showcasing 3d animated models in Unity.

I have one where I can update the current frame of the animation, but when playing the animation frame doesn't update the slider.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NewAnimController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Slider slider;
    public Animator animator;

    private AnimationState anim;

    void Start()
    {
        animator.speed = 0.0001f;
        slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChanged);
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>()["Take 001"];

    }

    void Update ()
    {
        anim.time = slider.value;
    }

    public void OnValueChanged(float changedValue)
    {
        animator.speed = 0.0001f;
        animator.Play("Take 001", -1, slider.normalizedValue);
    }
```

Please help. Many thanks

Comment: Youtube has a scrubber, you use it to move the current time to the desired place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ridiculously easy in ordinary Unity.UI (2016) ...

1 - click "add canvas"

2 - click "add slider"

3 - **one line of code** in `Update`...

```
GetComponent<Slider>.value = .. your animation time ..
```

That's it!

If you prefer a different slider knob, just drag in a different image. Change the slider width, colors etc as you like in the editor.

---

Note for future readers, to get an animation time it seems to be usually

```
float t = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime;
```

Comment: Is the code you've provided in c# or js?

Also does the slider work both ways, with the animation updating the slider as it plays, and if you move the slider it then changes the current frame of the animation?

Comment: Not on this question I think I'm good, I'll see what I can implement from the other question, many thanks for your help.